# Excel Index/Match Formula Returning #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that is finding the closest time match to a user entered time. The formula works great when the Time column does not have any blank cells, but the second it sees a blank cell, I get the #VALUE! error. How do I get this formula to exclude blank cells and only index/match existing data?

`{=INDEX(B2:B5000,MATCH(MIN(ABS('User Input'!G8-B2:B5000)),ABS('User Input'!G8-B2:B5000),-1))}`

[image]

Comment: change the `-1` to `0`

Comment: Related to the `-1` for a `>= value`, see [the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), which states that the lookup range order has to be **Descending**, i.e., Z to A, or largest to smallest. (see [sort data documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654)).  Basically, you need to sort before you attempt, so no blanks, etc.

Comment: @ Scott, That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your lookup range cannot guarantee a sort, since you use the ABS() value of a data operation. The new XLookup() function which was just released to the Office 365 monthly channel can do a simpler formula that does not require any sorting.

```
=XLOOKUP(MIN(ABS(Sheet2!A1-B2:B10)),ABS(Sheet2!A1-B2:B10),B2:B10,,1)
```

If you can't use XLookup, you could use a helper column (e.g. in column C, with the formula `=ABS('User Input'!$G$8-B2)` , copy down and sort the data by that column. Then you can simplify the Index/Match to

```
=INDEX(C2:C5000,MATCH(MIN(C2:C5000),C2:C5000,-1))
```

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I can get IT to upgrade my Excel so that I have that. Currently I do not have xlookup.

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer